# SBT Scaladoc configuration for the standard library

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

I'd like to setup ScalaDoc to link to the standard library, from SBT. I'm using 0.12.4 but I'm going to switch to 0.13 soon. Moreover, I'd like to make the setup simple by using 0.13's support.

The best option would be automatic mapping with [0.13's `autoAPIMappings`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/scaladoc.html#auto-link):

```
//Requires SBT 0.13. However, automatic mapping does not work for the standard library.
autoAPIMappings := true
```

The `scala-library` should support it because [its pom](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.2/scala-library-2.10.2.pom) sets `info.apiURL`, and [that's what SBT reads](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7201).

However, this does not work. Neither `String` nor `GenTraversable` are hyperlinked. `last` shows that no option is added to `scaladoc` arguments.

So:

1. how can I fix `autoAPIMappings`?
2. are there alternatives?
3. I've not observed this feature working, but maybe I just need another package which sets `info.apiUrl`. Any packages come to mind? Google seems unhelpful, and it's unobvious how to query for maven packages with some properties, or even how to do full-text search on poms. `find ~/.m2 ~/.ivy2 -name '*.pom' -type f|xargs grep info.apiUrl` found no results among my 2G of local caches.

(This question might seem a dup of [SBT Scaladoc Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807427/sbt-scaladoc-configuration), but it's for updated configuration and with a different SBT version, so the question is different; moreover, the existing answer shows a deprecated solution).

Comment: `autoAPIMappings := true` works on a minimal test case for me, using Scala 2.10.2 and sbt 0.13.0.  `Option`, `Int`, and `GenTraversable` link ok and `last` shows the proper option.  `String` does not, because it goes to java.lang.String, which is javadoc and not supported by scaladoc.

Comment: @MarkHarrah: Thanks for the answer! But it doesn't work for me on this minimal testcase (both Int and Option fail, no option passed): https://gist.github.com/Blaisorblade/6529621
Am I doing something wrong there, or should I open an issue? Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works for me.  You might a) look at the pom in your .ivy2/cache and verify it has `info.apiURL` b) look at `show compile:doc:apiMappings`, which should have the Map of `File->URL` passed in `doc` c) look at `show compile:doc::autoApiMappings` to verify that is enabled. d) look at `about` to verify the sbt and Scala versions being used.  e) check that `~/.sbt/0.13/` doesn't have anything set.

Comment: @MarkHarrah: I figured out the problem: downloading scala-library with 0.12.4 (or .x I guess) will create a bad ivy descriptor.

(a) was the problem: SBT 0.12.4 doesn't generate enough metadata in the ivy file (not the POM, I didn't find any in the Ivy cache - and the POM is OK). This was reflected in `apiMappings` being empty while the rest was fine. The Ivy file contained mention of info.apiUrl, but only in a different tag.

All data is available at https://github.com/Blaisorblade/sbt-test-case-apiUrl, instructions to reproduce are in the last commit. And clean+update on 0.13 is no fix.

Comment: That's disappointing and will be a common problem.  Only 0.13 knows that the `info.apiURL` property is important and should be made into an extra attribute.  Clean `~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/ivy-2.10.2.xml`.  Please open a bug.  I'm not sure it can be worked around, but we'll see.

Answer (score 7):

I know no solution for `autoAPIMappings`, but here are some alternatives.

1. A possible alternative, using [0.13's `apiMappings`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/scaladoc.html#manual-api-links), one can setup a manual mapping. On my system, `last doc` shows that this adds `-doc-external-doc:/Users/pgiarrusso/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.2/lib/scala-library.jar#http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/` to the command line, and it works.

   ```
   apiMappings += (scalaInstance.value.libraryJar -> url(s"http://www.scala-lang.org/api/${scalaVersion.value}/"))
   ```

This requires Scaladoc 2.10.2 or later.

2. Alternatively, one can add the same option by hand. This is necessary on SBT 0.12. The main nontrivial step is to find the right library.

   In 0.13 syntax:

   ```
   scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) += s"-doc-external-doc:${scalaInstance.value.libraryJar}#http://www.scala-lang.org/api/${scalaVersion.value}/"
   ```

   In 0.12 syntax:

   ```
   scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) <+= (scalaVersion, scalaInstance) map { (scalaVer, scalaIn) =>
     "-doc-external-doc:" + scalaIn.libraryJar + "#http://www.scala-lang.org/api/" + scalaVer + "/"}
   ```

   This option still requires Scaladoc 2.10.2.
3. Finally, on older Scaladocs one can use `-external-urls`, even though it is less precise (and thus deprecated), as [@MarkHarrah had suggested earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807427/sbt-scaladoc-configuration/13832171#13832171).

   In 0.13 syntax:

   ```
   scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) += s"-external-urls:scala=http://www.scala-lang.org/api/${scalaVersion.value}/"
   ```

   In 0.12 syntax:

   ```
   scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) <+= scalaVersion map (scalaVer => "-external-urls:scala=http://www.scala-lang.org/api/" + scalaVer + "/")
   ```

Finally, note that in all cases occurrences of `String` do not become a hyperlink, maybe because of some bug with type aliases. However, other types (including `GenTraversable`) are hyperlinked.

Comment: Note: the comments to the question discuss the problems with `autoAPIMappings`, I should incorporate a summary into the answer.

Comment: Update: the problem should be fixed for 0.13.1, see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/876.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use this plugin:

https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/sbt-api-mappings

And the external references will be resolved.

Comment: This is SO good! Doesn't work for doobie, though. It generates a link, but the link is invalid.

Comment: please create a pull requesr for the library

Comment: The problem is that doobie isn't published to maven central... yet. As soon as it does, it ought to work.