# Can I use sbt's `apiMappings` setting for managed dependencies?

Tags: sbt, scaladoc

I'd like the ScalaDoc I generate with sbt to link to external libraries, and in sbt 0.13 we have `autoAPIMappings` which is supposed to add these links for libraries that declare their `apiURL`. In practice though, none of the libraries I use provide this in their pom/ivy metadata, and I suspect some of these libraries will never do so.

The `apiMappings` setting is supposed to help with just that, but it is typed as `Map[File, URL]` and hence geared towards setting doc urls for unmanaged dependencies. Managed dependencies are declared as instances of `sbt.ModuleID` and cannot be inserted directly in that map.

Can I somehow populate the `apiMappings` setting with something that will associate an URL with a managed dependency ?

A related question is: does sbt provide an idiomatic way of getting a `File` from a `ModuleID`? I guess I could try to evaluate some classpaths and get back `File`s to try and map them to `ModuleID`s but I hope there is something simpler.

Note: this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747265/sbt-scaladoc-configuration-for-the-standard-library/18747266, but that question differs by linking to the scaladoc for the standard library, for which there is a well known `File` `scalaInstance.value.libraryJar`, which is not the case in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get this working for referencing scalaz and play by doing the following:

```scala
apiMappings ++= {
  val cp: Seq[Attributed[File]] = (fullClasspath in Compile).value
  def findManagedDependency(organization: String, name: String): File = {
    ( for {
        entry <- cp
        module <- entry.get(moduleID.key)
        if module.organization == organization
        if module.name.startsWith(name)
        jarFile = entry.data
      } yield jarFile
    ).head
  }
  Map(
      findManagedDependency("org.scalaz",        "scalaz-core") -> url("https://scalazproject.ci.cloudbees.com/job/nightly_2.10/ws/target/scala-2.10/unidoc/")
    , findManagedDependency("com.typesafe.play", "play-json")   -> url("http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/api/scala/")
  )
}
```

YMMV of course.

Comment: I don't have my build files handy at the moment, but on the whole this looks like the solution I had cobbled together in the time since asking the question, if maybe somewhat simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is good, but it'll fail when assumptions about exact project dependencies don't hold. Here's a variation that might prove useful:

```scala
apiMappings ++= {
  def mappingsFor(organization: String, names: List[String], location: String, revision: (String) => String = identity): Seq[(File, URL)] =
    for {
      entry: Attributed[File] <- (fullClasspath in Compile).value
      module: ModuleID <- entry.get(moduleID.key)
      if module.organization == organization
      if names.exists(module.name.startsWith)
    } yield entry.data -> url(location.format(revision(module.revision)))

  val mappings: Seq[(File, URL)] =
    mappingsFor("org.scala-lang", List("scala-library"), "http://scala-lang.org/api/%s/") ++
      mappingsFor("com.typesafe.akka", List("akka-actor"), "http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/%s/") ++
      mappingsFor("com.typesafe.play", List("play-iteratees", "play-json"), "http://playframework.com/documentation/%s/api/scala/index.html", _.replaceAll("[\\d]$", "x"))

  mappings.toMap
}
```

(Including `scala-library` here is redundant, but useful for illustration purposes.)

If you perform `mappings foreach println`, you'll get output like (note that I don't have Akka in my dependencies):

```
(/Users/michaelahlers/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.7.jar,http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/)
(/Users/michaelahlers/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-iteratees_2.11/jars/play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.6.jar,http://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/)
(/Users/michaelahlers/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11/jars/play-json_2.11-2.4.6.jar,http://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/)
```

This approach:

1. Allows for none or many matches to the module identifier.
2. Concisely supports multiple modules to link the same documentation.

   - Or, with `Nil` provided to `names`, all modules for an organization.
3. Defers to the module as the version authority.

   - But lets you map over versions as needed.

     - As in the case with Play's libraries, where *x* is used for the patch number.

Those improvements allow you to create a separate SBT file (call it `scaladocMappings.sbt`) that can be maintained in a single location and easily copy and pasted into any project.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to my last suggestion, the [sbt-api-mappings plugin](http://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/sbt-api-mappings) by [ThoughtWorks](http://thoughtworks.com) shows a lot of promise. Long term, that's a far more sustainable route than each project maintaining its own set of mappings.