# Using apiMappings for Java documentation in sbt?

Tags: sbt

How to use `apiMappings` in sbt for javadoc? See [Can I use sbt's `apiMappings` setting for managed dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786841/can-i-use-sbts-apimappings-setting-for-managed-dependencies/20919304#20919304)

Comment: How do you generate javadoc for the project? Isn't it the same as scaladoc as described in http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/scaladoc.html#generate-javadoc-or-scaladoc?