# Problems with Scaladoc Linking to Classes in Comment Blocks

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

I may be missing something obvious, but I can't get Scaladoc to link to classes—only to companion objects. Consider these examples.

This works fine:

```
/** Returns a [[scala.List]] (also known as [[scala.collection.immutable.List]]). */
```

While this won't link, with `Could not find any member to link for "play.api.libs.json.JsObject"` logged as a warning:

```
/** Seems [[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]] is invalid. */
```

This (taking into account [disambiguation syntax](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/test/scaladoc/resources/links.scala)), however, *will* link:

```
/** Seems [[play.api.libs.json.JsObject$]] is liked. */
```

[I've got external API mappings sorted out in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35673212/700420) and generated documentation of function signatures links correctly to external site, so I'm (fairly) certain this isn't related to my problem.

Where am I going wrong? (Or is this a bug?)